# Number of cycles in a certain graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a certain problem I am asked to find how many $4$-cycles are there in the graph $C_4 + K_9$, where $C_4,K_9$ are the $4$-cyclic graph and the complete graph of $9$ vertices, respectively. Here, the addition means that both graphs are connected by exactly and edge and nothing else. Here is my approach:

There is an obvious $4$-cycle in $C_4$. The main problem comes at counting how many are there. In the other one. I choose $4$ vertices over $9$ to form the cycle ($9 \choose 4$). Then, if the order does not matter there are $3$ different cycles that can be made with those $3$ vertices (I made it by hand. However, if the order matters, there are $3! = 6$ different $4$-cycles. Therefore, the final answer I would give would be $1 + {9 \choose 4}\cdot3$ if the order does not matter and $1 + {9 \choose 4}\cdot6 $ if it matters. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer $1 + \binom94 \cdot 3$ is correct, and is the most reasonable way of counting $4$-cycles in my opinion: specifically, it counts subgraphs of $C_4 + K_9$ which are isomorphic to $C_4$.

The answer becomes $2 + \binom 94 \cdot 6$ if *orientation* matters: not $1 + \binom94 \cdot 6$, since the orientation of the $4$-cycle in $C_4$ should also matter. Formally, we can think of the undirected graph $C_4 + K_9$ as a directed graph in which every undirected edge is replaced by two directed edges going in either direction - then count the number of subgraphs isomorphic to a *directed* $C_4$.

The second answer, in my opinion, is not particularly natural - you can tell by how long the explanation is of what it formally means. So the first answer is better. But there is also a third answer!

We can also think of a $4$-cycle as a sequence $(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_1)$ such that all $4$ vertices $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ are distinct, and all $4$ edges $v_1v_2$, $v_2v_3$, $v_3v_4$, $v_4v_1$ are present in the graph. This is how I would interpret "order matters". In this case, $C_4 + K_9$ contains $8 + \binom 94 \cdot 24$ different $4$-cycles! Each subgraph isomorphic to $C_4$ can be turned into $8$ different $4$-cycles, by choosing a starting point *and* a direction of travel.

The third answer is occasionally useful - some counting methods naturally produce answers more like the third answer than the first. However, if you have the choice, the first answer is the simplest one to give, because the second and third answers are just $2\times$ and $8\times$ the first, respectively.